# Generalized Sphere Kissing Problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, sphere-packing

I am currently researching discrete geometry and I am in need of an upper bound on a generalized kissing number in 3-dimensions dependent upon a parameter $\eta$ which is the radii of spheres touching a central unit ball.

That is, center the unit ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ at the origin and define $k_{s}(\eta)$ to be the maximum number of balls of radius $\eta$ which can kiss $B$ and form a solid packing (non-overlapping interiors). How can you upper bound $k_{s}(\eta)$ for $\eta >0$? A remarkable case of note is $k_{s}(1) = 12$ which corresponds to the solution of the Newton-Gregory problem.

Comment: How sharp a bound do you need? Comparing volumes gives you one, but that is horribly far from the actual number. Might be enough for certain theoretical purposes though, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: @AchimKrause: I am attempting to improve an upper bound regarding non-congruent sphere packings and need a bound which is as tight as possible; I'm not sure how I close need yet. I'm not sure what technique you intend to employ by comparing volumes.

Comment: Well, projecting the balls kissing B onto the surface of B gives a disjoint circles on the unit 2-sphere. By computing their area and comparing it to the total area, you obtain an upper bound. For example, in the $\eta=1$-case, this gives 16, which I think is way too bad for your purposes.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: I need bounds for large $\eta$ as well. I'm not sure I see the equivalence, would you perhaps be able to explain as the answer to this question?

Comment: Anton's answer give bounds for all $\eta$, the bounds are only more precise for small $\eta$. The point is that packing spheres kissing a sphere is the same as finding a spherical code, which makes your question redundant.

Comment: @BenoitKloeckner: Is the upper bound then given by $k_{s}(\eta) < \text {vol}(S^2)/(\frac{\pi \eta^2}{3})$? There are some typos in Anton Petrunin's answer, so I'm still confused. Or do we not have \eta = \theta and instead express $\theta = 2\arcsin(\eta / (\eta +1)) $?

Comment: @SamuelReid: my point is that this question being a duplicate, it should be discussed at the question mentionned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to write a paper which eventually answered my problem, although it happens to be hid inside the $A^{\text{LP}}(3,\theta)$ term in the bound of Theorem 1 of my paper which is under review at the Journal of Geometry:

"Upper Bounds for Non-Congruent Sphere Packings" ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00407))